# Rails Rspec testing html select options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec-rails

I'm trying to use rspec to test for selecting a value from the select tag.  The select tag should list all names of every user in the database.  It works when I navigate through the site.  But the test doesn't seem to see the FactoryGirl-created user names:

The error is:

```
cannot select option, no option with text 'Person 4' in select box 'receiver_id'
```

Here is a portion of the message_pages spec:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before do
    select other_user.name, :from => 'message[receiver_id]'
    fill_in "Subject", with: "Hello"
    fill_in "Body", with: "It's time to have fun!"
end
```

Here's the HTML output of my view:

```
<label for="message_receiver_id">Receiver</label>
<select id="message_receiver_id" name="message[receiver_id]"><optionvalue="12">John</option>
<option value="13">Tom</option>
<option value="9">Jay</option>
<option value="14">Bob</option></select>
```

Comment: I used select user.name instead and it passes.  Apparently other_user wasn't getting created?  I'm using a FactoryGirl sequencer.

Comment: You can use `let!` to avoid lazy evaluation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a lazy evaluation problem, common when using `let`. From the [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let):

> Note that let is lazy-evaluated: it is not evaluated until the first time the method it defines is invoked. You can use let! to force the method’s invocation before each example.

So both `user` and `other_user` will only be created when you first call them, and if you have already rendered the page then it's too late. Try switching the `let` calls to `let!` and see if that fixes things.

(It's funny though that you say that switching to `user.name` works. Can you post what other initialization code is in the spec?)

Comment: I think you're right.  I actually did invoke user before I get to the select testing, but I never invoked other_user.  Thanks!  Now I know what lazy evaluation is

Comment: That would explain why `user` worked but `other_user` didn't. Glad the answer helped!